# Hibernate mark message as 'read'

Tags: java, sql, json, hibernate

My application has an entity `Message` which is either 'read' or 'unread.'

Clients can ask for either read or unread messages or both (among other criteria). What I want to do is return some attributes of result set as a JSON object and if there was an unread message in this result set, mark them as read and persist their status to database.

Trivially we can do this by first iterating the result set and extracting the required data, and after that reiterating the same set and updating the necessary message.

But is this the optimal way? Can't we make use of sql triggers or some hibernate features?

Comment: You have to choose with SQL you can select messages and filter them out out in where clause similar with hibernate HQL, or you can use Hibernate/JPA criteria API.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for your response, I'm familiar with both standard query language and hibernate query language. I can use both to filter my desired result. What I'm looking for is to have a mechanism that will automatically mark the unread messages that are selected after I have extracted their information.

Comment: I'd say you have to issue UPDATE on desired records from messages table.

Comment: Sure I can call SQL UPDATE on records in the result set but I want this to be done automatically, meaning that I'm wondering if result set produced by calling SQL SELECT, can have SQL UPDATE called on them automatically...

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing like trigger before/after select. Only thing you can do is to create stored procedure for obtaining data and in this procedure update records, but I'd say this is dirty hacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Update records with another update statement.
2. Create stored procedure for obtaining data.
3. JPA spec contains @PostLoad annotation, you can read about it [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics). But I'd be very careful with this since hibernate can issue load on Message entity anytime (well someone else from your team calls load and your records are screwed).